# Type inference fails even though argument would be assignable: []any does not satisfy ~[]string

Tags: go, generics

The first calls to `slices.Insert()` below work, but the last doesn't.  I know it can be worked around (with an ugly cast), but what is the difference?  Why the inconsistency?

```
    const c = "C"
    var s string = "B"
    n := []interface{}{"Z"}
    n = slices.Insert(n, 0, "A") // OK
    n = slices.Insert(n, 0, c)   // OK
    n = slices.Insert(n, 0, s)   // S (type []interface{}) does not satisfy ~[]E
```

[see this code on the Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/dQt5d18tD5i)

Answer (score 2):

This is because of an interaction between inference of type parameters and the weird go fact that consts (both literal and declared with the `const` keyword) are untyped unless an explicit type is given.

First, let's check the declaration of `slices.Insert`: it's `func Insert[S ~[]E, E any](s S, i int, v ...E) S` That means the last argument(s) have to be of some type `E`, and the first argument has to be some type that has an underlying type `[]E` (that's what `~[]E` means).

When you write `slices.Insert(n, 0, "A")` then the inferred type `E` is `any`; `n` is declared to be of type `[]interface{}` which is `[]any` (because `any` is an alias for `interface{}`), and "A" is an untyped constant which can be given the type `any`.

The same logic applies to your second case; the only difference there is that you're using a named constant rather than a literal string constant.

The third case is wrong; the first argument is of type `[]any` and the variable `s` is of type `string`. There's no possible `E` here to make the types right — while a string can be assigned to a variable of type `any`, such an assignment includes an implicit type conversion.

The compiler has inferred `E=string` because of the final argument, and therefore complains because the type of `n` does not have underlying type `[]string` ("[]any does not implement ~[]string"). It could have inferred `E=any` (because of the underlying type of `n`) and complained that `s` is of type `string` and not `any`, and I think this would have led to a clearer error message in this case.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I now understand it is a problem of inference.  Sure the error message could be better but the compiler should infer `(s []any, i int, v...any)` rather than `(s []any, i int, v...string)` since it knows that E == any and a string (or anything) is implicitly converted to `any`

Comment: Also "A" is not an untyped constant - I can't see how it can be anything but a string

Comment: You're right that inferring `E=any` would work, but inference doesn't take into account possible implicit conversions in the current version of the compiler. And `"A"` is an untyped constant, not of type `string` (although its default type is `string`). A program like `type S string ; var s S = "hello"` compiles because of this, whereas `type S string; var s S = string("hello")` does not. See https://go.dev/ref/spec#Constants

Comment: Note that "untyped" here means it's not been assigned a type, not that it can be assigned to anything. Same for constants like `1` -- it's also an untyped constant (because it can eventually be uses as a range of types -- `int`, `uint8`, `float64` , etc. as well as types with these numeric types as their underlying type).

Comment: I think in a case like  `func F[T](a, b T) []T { return []T{a, b} }` one wouldn't want the compiler to infer `T=any` in a call like `F("a", 42)`, so taking into account possible implicit conversions is perhaps not desirable.

Comment: the constants are never "given" the type `any`, they are simply assignable to the `any` parameters after (if) instantiation succeeds

Answer (score 0):

As per the language specification, [type inference](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Type_inference) kicks in whenever a function call omits explicit type arguments. Then (emphasis mine):

> Type inference gives precedence to type information obtained from typed operands **before considering untyped constants**.

For the first two calls, both the literal `"A"` and `c` are untyped constants which are not considered for the first inference step.

Instead only `n` which is `[]any` is considered. Therefore `S` is inferred to be `[]any`, `E` is inferred to be `any` and the function can be instantiated because all type parameters are known.

*After instantiation succeeds*, the constants `"A"` and `c` in both cases default to type `string` — not `any` as the other answer incorrectly suggests — and `string` is assignable to the parameter `E` instantiated as `any`.

In the third case, type inference attempts to solve the type equations given by the argument-to-parameter assignability and type-parameter-to-constraint satisfiability. In the language spec, this section is rather complex, but basically it boils down to the following:

Given `func Insert[S ~[]E, E any](s S, i int, v ...E) S` called with `n, 0, s`,

- `n` must be assignable to `S`
- `S` must satisfy `~[]E`

and:

- `s` (the string) must be assignable to `E`
- `E` must satisfy `any`

The type equation solver solves for `S` and `E` (the unknown type parameters) at the same time, and fails because in the two sets of equations `n -> S -> ~[]E` and `s -> E -> any` the type parameter `E` evaluates to different types: `any` in the first and `string` in the second.

Therefore, in the third case the function *does not get instantiated*, and the fact that `string` argument is assignable to the `any` parameter doesn't even come into the picture.

As a matter of fact, note that if you instantiate the type parameters with `[]any` and `any` explicitly, the third call compiles:

```
slices.Insert[[]any, any](n, 0, s)
```

*but*, you must supply **both** `S` and `E` otherwise type inference kicks in — and fails.